# List.Contains returns false, even though it seems it should return true

Tags: vb.net, list, contains

```
Sub pageload() Handles Me.Load
    Dim bom As New List(Of Car)

    Dim car1 As New Car With {.Name = "Pea", .Year = 2}
    Dim car2 As New Car With {.Name = "Pea", .Year = 2}

    bom.Add(car1)

    MsgBox(bom.Contains(car2))
End Sub
```

WHY??? I mean the object has the exactly same data, so why does it say it is not contained?

Comment: You have two cars. Both happen to be the same colour and model. The first is on the list, the second is not. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: And what about the GetHashCode? It's also not the same. What does it actually do?

Comment: Indeed. You are viewing `Car` as a value type. Think of it from a  "real world" perspective (OOP is all about modeling data after real-world objects, after all): If I drive to your house in a Red Toyota Camry, and then upon leaving I break into *your* Red Toyota Camry and drive it home, did I leave with the same car I arrived in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Contains` method tests equality by calling the `Equals` method on objects. Unless you override the `Equals` method in the `Car` class and implement your own means of comparison, instances of `Car` will be considered equal by means of *referential identity* (being the exact same object) not based on their contents being equal.

Those objects you created are definitely not the same object. Proof: changing one will not change the other.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `car` is a **reference type**, not a value type.  The two car objects you create are completely separate things.  Each points to a different place in memory, even though they happen to have all the same properties.  Think of them like identical twins.  One gets into a truck.  If you ask if the **other one** is in the truck, the answer is no, even though in a sense they are *exactly the same*.

If you had defined `car2` and then set it equal to car1 (`Dim car2 As New Car = car1`), then you would have to pointers to the exact same place in memory.  Your result would have been true.  Both variables would have referred to the same car object.

Now, if this was a **value type**, like an integer or date (or structure.  And a string behaves this way also.), then any values that are the same would be considered the same.  You put $10 in a car, and I ask if $10 is in the car.  The answer is yes, and it doesn't matter if it was my $10 or your $10.

You example is a great example of a key difference in how reference types and value types behave.

For reference types by default, the *Equals* property check to see if two objects are references to the exact same place in memory, not whether all the values are the same.  (*Contains* uses the *Equals* property.)  You could override that behavior for particular objects if you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Your two cars are completely independent one of each other.

`Contains` checks whether any list item *points to the same object* like the parameter you provide. And not whether these two objects are logically equal.

If you want it to do this, you should override the `Equals`-method of your `Car`