# VB.NET - List.Contains Returns False But Should be True

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I had a look at [List.Contains returns false, even though it seems it should return true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283645/list-contains-returns-false-even-though-it-seems-it-should-return-true) but his code structure is a bit different to mine so im unsure if I have the same issue.

Before I continue, Let me explain what my result should be.
We have 2 input files, File 1 with `email:hash`'s the other with a mix of `email:hash` and `email:plain`.

End output: If the Second file has plaintext after :, Output it (Making sure not to make duplicates when outputting file 1's email:hash's if no file 2 line for that email/hash is made), Otherwise output with the Hash.

tl;dr - Basically make the Second File `overwrite prioritized` over the First File.

```
(First File Randomized)
ABC_123@gmail.com:f6deea50e7eeb2d930fab83ccc32cdfe
123abc@domain.ext:82e6eeea4060c90cc3dc6ddd25885806
123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd
abc123@email.com:2d366131008f89781b8379bed3451656

(Second File Randomized)
123abc@domain.ext:aaaaaaaa
ABC_123@gmail.com:cccccccc
abc123@email.com:bbbbbbbb
newemail@hotmail.com:ddddddddd

Output should be:
123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd
123abc@domain.ext:aaaaaaaa
ABC_123@gmail.com:cccccccc
abc123@email.com:bbbbbbbb
newemail@hotmail.com:ddddddddd

(Output from Tests - "->" lines shouldn't be outputted.)
123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd
->123abc@domain.ext:82e6eeea4060c90cc3dc6ddd25885806
123abc@domain.ext:aaaaaaaa
ABC_123@gmail.com:cccccccc
->ABC_123@gmail.com:f6deea50e7eeb2d930fab83ccc32cdfe
abc123@email.com:bbbbbbbb
newemail@hotmail.com:ddddddddd
```

<strike>In the Second OpenFileDialog Block it always returns false until the LAST line in the `For Each combo as Match in matches`.
Weirdly, If I change the second regex from `(.*)@(.*):(.*)` to `(.*)@(.*):([a-f0-9]{32})` it for some reason works, The issue with that is it will only match `Email@domain.ext:{md5}` and won't match for example `Email@domain.ext:abc123` which is a requirement.</strike>
<strike>(Latest code update where I was messing around to try fix it broke it even more so this doesn't even work now).</strike>

I slept for once and came back on to try fix it, So far im almost there, It's overwriting correctly except for on one email:hash for some reason.

[Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UMAA.gif)
As you can see it changed the 123abc@domain.ext from the hash to aaaaaaa but for the ABC_123@gmail.com it didn't for some strange reason. Also yes the abc123@email.com hash does change so it's odd that a random email:hash didn't change.

I have been at this for about <strike>9</strike> 12+ hours straight. (No Exaggeration) and i'd really love an enlightenment on what's going on.

I have tried so many alternatives and such that I can't even remember at this point.

Code: **(Updated x3)**
Reminder: Read above on what im trying to achieve :)

```
#Region "Merge Combo's"

    Private Sub List_Merge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles List_Merge.Click

        Dim ofd = New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd.Title = "Import..."
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        ofd.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
        ofd.Multiselect = True

        'If the user selects 2 Files;
        If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK And ofd.CheckFileExists = True) Then

            'Make sure there are no previously stored Conversions;
            ActionList2.Items.Clear()

            'Variables;
            Dim MergedCombos As Integer = 0
            Dim TotalCombos As Integer = 0

            Try

                For Each filename As String In ofd.FileNames

                    Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)

                        Dim result = filename.Union(filename, New MailEqualityComparer)

                        'Get all Matches found from the Regex Condition;
                        Dim combos As MatchCollection = New Regex("^([^@]+)@(.*):(.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

                        'Add each Match to the ActionList except for Duplicates;
                        For Each combo As Match In combos

                            'Increment the Total Combo's count;
                            TotalCombos += 1

                            'If the ActionList doesn't contain the same Combo;
                            If Not ActionList2.Items.Contains(combo.Value) Then

                                'If the email is already in the ActionList;
                                If IsInListbox(ActionList2, combo.Groups(1).Value + "@" + combo.Groups(2).Value) = True Then

                                    'This combo is presumed to be a Hash Decrypted Combo - Overwrite it with the Encrypted Hash;
                                    ActionList2.Items.Add(combo.Value)

                                    'Remove the Hash Item from ActionList;
                                    ActionList2.Items.RemoveAt(FindListboxIndex(ActionList2, combo.Groups(1).Value + "@" + combo.Groups(2).Value))

                                Else

                                    'Add the Combo;
                                    ActionList2.Items.Add(combo.Value)

                                End If

                            End If

                        Next

                    End Using

                Next

            Catch ex As Exception

                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString)

            Finally

                'If atleast 1 Item is in the ActionList, Enable the Export Button;
                If ActionList2.Items.Count > 0 Then
                    ExportButton.Enabled = True
                    ExportButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(149, 255, 141)
                End If

                'Update the Merged Combo's count;
                StatusBar_LeftText.Text = MergedCombos.ToString

                'If MergedCombos are less than TotalCombos, Add a "x Duplicates Removed" message;
                If MergedCombos < TotalCombos Then
                    StatusBar_LeftText.Text += " - " + (TotalCombos - MergedCombos).ToString + " Duplicates Removed"
                End If

                'Autoscroll;
                ActionList2.TopIndex = ActionList2.Items.Count - 1

            End Try

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function FindListboxIndex(lb As ListBox, searchString As String) As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To lb.Items.Count - 1
            If lb.Items(i).ToString().Contains(searchString) Then
                Return i
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function

    Private Function IsInListbox(lb As ListBox, searchString As String) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To lb.Items.Count - 1
            If lb.Items(i).ToString().Contains(searchString) Then
                Return True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

#End Region
```

Comment: No one has a single comment? Anything you guys think I should try? Test? etc? Nothing? o.o

Comment: If you guys cant find a way to help - Please upvote my Question as thats the purpose of it, Upvoting will help others find my Question = More possibility of an Answer/Suggestion! Thanks

Comment: Still need answers - The code above should work but it doesn't ALWAYS work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, I think this should fit to your Needs.

```
    Dim ofd = New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Title = "Import..."
    ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    ofd.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
    ofd.Multiselect = True

    Dim output As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'key = mail, value = plain/hash

    If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK And ofd.CheckFileExists = True) Then

        For Each filename As String In ofd.FileNames
            Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)

                Dim combos As MatchCollection = New Regex("(.*)@(.*):(.*)").Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

                For Each match As Match In combos
                    Dim tmp() As String = Split(match.ToString, ":")
                    tmp(1) = tmp(1).Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "") 'Delete carriage return
                    If Not output.ContainsKey(tmp(0)) Then
                        output.Add(tmp(0), tmp(1))
                    Else
                        If output(tmp(0)).Length = 32 Then 'condition whether to change the value or not. You need to design it to your needs.
                            output(tmp(0)) = tmp(1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next match
            End Using

        Next filename
    End If
```

I don't know if there is a carriage return in your data. I tried with simple txt files and there was.
You need to change the condition to your needs. I saw the hashes have 32 signs and the plain text does not..

Comment: The thing is, The file order could be different. So file1() might have file2()'s content so this wouldnt really work would it?

Comment: This is why I started with file2. It means all data from file2 is put into the dictionary. It means all email:plain is stored. Then open file1 and check if email is available. If not, add email:hash. If yes, do not add, because you want to have the email:plain. I think this should work. It is working with your given input example.

Comment: As I said your example doesnt work the files order can be different depending how the user selects and opens the file

Comment: I see. How do you check wether the string is hash or plain text?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the union of the two set of lines you have and that's exactly what `Enumerable.Union` do provided we have a way to distinguish equal elements.

Starting from this we first define that equality comparer :

```
Class MailEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String)

    Overloads Function Equals(mail1 As String, mail2 As String) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String).Equals
        ' assume input validated
        Return mail1.Split(":"c)(0).Equals(mail2.Split(":"c)(0))
    End Function

    Overloads Function GetHashCode(mail As String) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String).GetHashCode
        ' assume input validated
        Return mail.Split(":"c)(0).GetHashCode
    End Function
End Class
```

That is for this class two string are equal if their part before the `:` are equal.

Then you just have to do the Union using an instance of that class to ensure proper equality :

```
    ' file1 and file2 are String arrays
    ' they could be the result of File.ReadAllLines for example

    Dim file1 = {
        "ABC_123@gmail.com: f6deea50e7eeb2d930fab83ccc32cdfe",
        "123abc@domain.ext:82e6eeea4060c90cc3dc6ddd25885806",
        "123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd",
        "abc123@email.com: 2d366131008f89781b8379bed3451656"
    }

    Dim file2 = {
        "123abc@domain.ext: aaaaaaaa",
        "ABC_123@gmail.com: cccccccc",
        "abc123@email.com: bbbbbbbb",
        "newemail@hotmail.com: ddddddddd"
    }

    ' result is an IEnumerable(Of String)
    ' add ToArray (for example) if you want to materialize the result
    Dim result = file2.Union(file1, New MailEqualityComparer) ' note the order ; it matters

    ' result content :
    ' ----------------
    ' 123abc@domain.ext: aaaaaaaa
    ' ABC_123@gmail.com: cccccccc
    ' abc123@email.com: bbbbbbbb
    ' newemail@hotmail.com: ddddddddd
    ' 123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd
```

It just leaves us with "how do we determine the order for Union parameters ?"
For that we have to have a way to know which file contains the "plain text" stuff, information you didn't provided at time of writing.

*(Note: the same could have been achieved using `Hashset(Of String)` or `SortedSet(Of String)` and their `UnionWith` method)

[SortedSet requires an `IComparer(Of String)` instead of an `IEqualityComparer(Of String)`]*

### Edit after comment

If I understood correctly your comment (which I'm not sure) ; here is what could be done using a SortedSet :

```
Class MailComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Function Compare(mail1 As String, mail2 As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        ' assume input validated
        Return mail1.Split(":"c)(0).CompareTo(mail2.Split(":"c)(0))
    End Function
End Class

' file1 and file2 are String arrays
' they could be the result of File.ReadAllLines for example
Dim file1 = {
    "ABC_123@gmail.com: f6deea50e7eeb2d930fab83ccc32cdfe",
    "123abc@domain.ext:82e6eeea4060c90cc3dc6ddd25885806",
    "123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd",
    "abc123@email.com: 2d366131008f89781b8379bed3451656"
}

Dim file2 = {
    "123abc@domain.ext: aaaaaaaa",
    "ABC_123@gmail.com: cccccccc",
    "abc123@email.com: bbbbbbbb",
    "newemail@hotmail.com: ddddddddd"
}

' allLines is an IEnumerable(Of String)
Dim allLines = file2.Concat(file1) ' note the order ; it matters

Dim result As New SortedSet(Of String)(allLines, New MailComparer)

' result content :
' ----------------
' 123_ABC@gmail.com:8fa5104d4d995dc153e5509ab988bcfd
' 123abc@domain.ext: aaaaaaaa
' ABC_123@gmail.com: cccccccc
' abc123@email.com: bbbbbbbb
' newemail@hotmail.com: ddddddddd
```

I don't see where it's not simple using an 8 lines class ; but maybe I missed the point...

Comment: Ok, Well how would I manage to use Hashset/Sortedset to order the lists appropriately?

Comment: The simpler would be to use a SortedSet for that (an HashSet doesn't have a notion of ordering) and make a class (like `MailEqualityComparer`) implementing `IComparer(Of String)` to give in it's constructor. Inside that class the `Compare` method will be responsible for the ordering you have to write the code to compare two inputs (two string here) and return -1, 0, 1 to signify the relative order between the two.

Comment: ... Another possible approach would be to make a type to store your input (splitting the email part and the hash/text part in two separate fields) and that class could implement `IComparable(Of TheClass)` allowing that way to compare instance between themselves (and possible other operation if you intend to use those string for more things)

Comment: At this point i'm lost to be honest :/ Could you please look at my Code in the OP and perhaps edit it to have your edits in it?

Comment: You dont really understand, Like it's identify'ing them and overwriting with the Plain Text just fine apart from on one hash which is strange. Is it necessary to be using all these new Classes/Functions etc? There surely must be a simpler way